# A.J. Hoge's student is conversing with you vs A.J. Hoge's student is conversing to you

Tags: grammar

What is correct "to" or "with" in sentence:

> A.J. Hoge's student is conversing **with** you.

or

> A.J. Hoge's student is conversing **to** you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You converse **with** people.

The word originally meant [*to dwell, to live with, to keep company with*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/converse#etymonline_v_18312), and then it evolved to mean **to communicate (with)**.

Unlike *communicate, chat, talk*, it describes the state (to be, to live, to dwell), not the action (to share, to exchange, to give).

You can also say

> They are conversing.